# Form to an other hidden thing with PayPal

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

Okay, maybe not good explained but I have this:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $output['Private']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://MYWEBSITE/index.php?code=succes&bruh=<?php echo $userid; ?>&money=">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Topup">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:Buy%20Now%20Button.png:NonHostedGuest">
<table>
<tbody><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="TopUp_amounth">How much?</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="200">$</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="submit" value="Top Up" name="submit">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Now I want a method to get what they insert the '`TopUp_amounth`' into the return url. The `TopUp_amount` people can choose by their own. But I want it go get in the return `url` to. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could send it to your own PHP script and rout it to your orginal link (PayPal) with `curl`

Like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['cmd'])){
$url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$fields = array(
    'cmd' => urlencode($_POST['cmd']),
    'business' => urlencode($_POST['business']),
    'return' => urlencode($_POST['return']),
  [...]
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
}
```

And your HTML-form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" target="_top">
 your form
</form>
```